# Excel: Find duplicates in one column, then remove rows based on value in other column

Tags: excel

I've been able to find a number of articles that seem to orbit my particular puzzle, but I'm having difficulty carving out the specific solution for it. Using the below image for reference:

```
ID  Name      Company Name
 5  Dennis E  Lantz Boggio Architects, Pc
 6  Director  Lantz Boggio Architects, Pc
 7  Glenn D   Lantz Boggio Architects, Pc
 8  Director  Ge Johnson Construction
 9  Evan Da   GH Phipps Construction Companies
10  Paul Fog  GH Phipps Construction Companies
11  Todd W    GH Phipps Construction Companies
```

I have a mailing list that is organized so each unique contact is placed on an individual row. The list contains columns for Name (column A in my sheet) and Company Name (column B).

If the Name cell was originally empty, a default 'generic' title is entered (e.g. 'Director', as per rows 6 and 8 in the image).

In some cases, there are multiple contacts at the same company (e.g. rows 5-7, 9-11). Occasionally, one of those contacts has a 'generic' name (e.g. row 6).

What I'd like to do:

- Search for duplicates in Column B
- Then delete the row based on the value in Column A (with me defining the specific values to be sought for)

So in the example image, only row 6 would be deleted because Column B contains a duplicate address, and Column A contains the value 'Director'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, in C5 and copied down to suit:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B5)>1,A5=C$1)
```

with `Director` in C1.

Then filter ColumnC to select `TRUE` and delete.

COUNTIF(B:B,B5) searches for the content of B5 throughout ColumnB (the `B:B`) and returns the count of the instances. B5 is within ColumnB so function will always find at least `1`, for duplicates more than one, so `>1` should detect that the row in question (`5` for example) is not the only instance.

However, *similar* entries will *not* be counted - for example those that end in a trailing space, when what is in B5 does not.

Comment: Thank you for responding! The formula is successfully comparing the values in the cells in Column A to the value entered into C1, but it doesn't seem to be including the needed duplicate ID condition from column B. I suppose the logic might read something like "IF Column B cell in row = Duplicate Address AND Column A cell in same row = Director OR Engineer OR Architect OR <whatever> THEN Delete'".

Comment: Thank you again. I'll certainly explore COUNTIFS next. It also looks like my earlier failure was due to user error on my part. I'm using column J as my 'workbench', and starting on row 2. I tried to modify your formula: `=AND(COUNTIF(B:B,B2)>1,A2=J$1)` and that seems to have broken it. When I tried your formula using just the rows in my example image and starting in C5, it worked perfectly (thank you again).

Comment: Understood. Could I pick your incredibly patient brain once more as to where I've gone wrong trying to start things in row 2? Just changing the starting row numbers (B5 to B2, and A5 to A2), using J1 (instead of C1 in your original solution) now as my reference value for column A, I'm able to find the matches to J1 in column A, but they're no longer restricted to dupe addresses in column B.

Comment: Got it! My final solution (using column J as my workbench column) `=AND(COUNTIF(B:B,$B2)>1,A2=J$1)` - thank you so much for the guidance!

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much again for the patient guidance. In the future, I'll be sure to better help those who are trying to help me. Thank you again!